# Passar variável php para javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Alguém me poderia dizer como passar uma variável PHP para o código em Javascript.
Eu sei que existem já muitos posts sobre isso e eu já tentei aplicar só que devo estar a fazer algo de errado por isso decidi pedir aqui ajuda.

```
<?php

   $ligacao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "publicidades");
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       echo "Erro na liga��o MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

   if($_POST["categoria"]){

      $sql_img = "SELECT distinct p.id_publicidade, p.nome, p.descricao, p.categoria, p.visualizacoes, p.estado, l.id_utilizador FROM publicidade p, linhapub l WHERE p.id_publicidade = l.id_publicidade and estado = 1 AND categoria IN (".$_POST["categoria"].") ORDER BY visualizacoes DESC";
      $imagem = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql_img);
      $objeto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($imagem);
      $attempts = $objeto["descricao"];
      $estado = $objeto["estado"];
      $utilizador = $objeto["id_utilizador"];

      $visu = "SELECT visualizacoes FROM publicidade WHERE id_publicidade ='".$objeto["id_publicidade"]."'";
      $obj = mysqli_query($ligacao, $visu);
      $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($obj);
      $final = $res["visualizacoes"];

      $num_post = mysqli_num_rows($imagem);
      if( $num_post ) {
         if($estado){
             if($final>0){
                echo "<img src=\"$attempts\" alt=\"Não deu!!\">";
                $alterar = "UPDATE publicidade SET visualizacoes  = visualizacoes-1 WHERE descricao = '$attempts'";
                $alteracao =  mysqli_query($ligacao, $alterar);
             }else{
                echo 'O seu tempo de antena acabou';
             }
         }
```

Eu aqui quero passar a variável `$utilizador` para esta função Javascript que está numa outra página:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var autoLoad = setInterval(
   function ()
   {
       var query="";
       for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
       query+= (i==0?"":",") + "'"+array[i]+"'";
       }
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "load_post.php",
      data: {categoria:query},
      success: function(dados){
          alert(dados);
      $('#load_post').html(dados);
          $('#load_post').fadeOut(5000);
        Lista(variavel);
      }
    });
      $('#load_post').fadeIn(5000);
   }, 5000); 
</script>
```

Eu depois quando tiver a variável quero chama-la na função `Lista()`

Eu estava a tentar fazer o envio pelo URL do `$utilizador` e depois fazer o GET na outra pagina mas por algum motivo não dá certo.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Primeiramente temos que entender que o PHP é uma linguagem *server-side* e Javascript *client-side*, dado esta informação sabemos então que o Javascript e interpretada pelo navegador, assim como o HTML e CSS, então da mesma maneira que você "escreve" HTML com o PHP você também pode "escrever" o Javascript (e de muitas maneiras, segue algumas delas):

**Direto no PHP**

```
<?php
    $utilizador = 'algum valor';
    echo '<script>var utilizador = "'. $utilizador .'";</script>';
```

---

**Direto no HTML/Script**

```
<script>
    var utilizador = <?=$utilizador?>;
</script>
```

Cuidado nos casos anteriores que, se o valor da variável no PHP for uma *string*, deve-se colocar aspas em torno da variável para evitar erros no Javascript:

```
    var utilizador = "<?=$utilizador?>";
```

---

**Pode passar um *array* como *json*:**

```
<script>
    var dados = <?=json_encode($objeto)?>
</script>
```

---

**Com jQuery.ajax**

<sub>ESSA OPÇÃO É PARA CASO AS VARIÁVEIS QUE VOCÊ DESEJA RESGATAR, NÃO ESTEJA NO MESMO ARQUIVO DO JAVASCRIPT</sub>

> Página com as variáveis (load_post.php)

```
<?php
    $var = Array(
        'attempts' =>   $objeto["descricao"],
        'estado' =>     $objeto["estado"],
        'utilizador' => $objeto["id_utilizador"]
    );

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($var);
    exit;
```

> Página com o Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load_post.php",
    data: {categoria:query},
    success: function(dados){
        alert(dados);
        $('#load_post').html(dados);
        $('#load_post').fadeOut(5000);
        Lista(dados.utilizador);
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, a sério. Eu ja estava a delirar um pouco desde as 12 horas que estou metido nisto e não estava a conseguir avançar. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Muito bom, simples e direto.

Answer (score 1):

Não ficou claro se o javascript está na mesma pagina, depois do PHP. Se estiver é simples:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var autoLoad = setInterval(
   function ()
   {
       var utilizador = "<?php echo $utilizador ?>";
```

Agora se estiver em outra página aí o melhor é com jquery.ajax()

Comment: Olá @IvanNack, bem vindo ao [pt.so]! Gostaria de pedir que você desenvolvesse um pouco mais a parte sobre utilizar o `jquery.ajax()` no contexto dessa pergunta, visto que isso pode ser a solução do problema tanto para o @OP quanto para outras pessoas que acessem a pergunta!

Answer (score 0):

Faz com o `$.ajax()` um POST para seu PHP, pega no seu PHP o `$objeto` e devolve ele no *ajax* com `<php>echo json_encode($objeto);`.

Comment: haha, valeu, me ajudou.. Bem mais simples.