# Passando valores JS para outra pagina HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

É possível pelo javascript passar uma variável seja ela global ou não de uma pagina HTML para outra HTML?

**index.html**
**recebe_variavel.html**

Tipo, alguma forma de salvar esse valor e pássalo para a outra pagina sem ter que utilizar o **php** como base.

Comment: LocalStorage, cookies, indexedDB, WebSQL e parâmetros GET são as formas que conheço. De uma pesquisada em cada uma, sempre temos o que aprender =) (recomendo o localstorage, simples e ie8+)

Comment: Relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58958/passar-variável-php-para-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sim, é possivel passar os valores por url.

Vou dar um exemplo com javascript.

Na index.html, crio uma função que recebe um parâmetro, que é o valor eu quero passar pra outra pagina.
Ao executar ela redireciona para a pagina que vai receber a variável, passando o valor por url.

```js
var passaValor= function(valor)
{
    window.location = "recebe_variavel.html?minhaVariavel="+valor;
}


var valorQueEuQueroPassar = 123;

 passaValor(valorQueEuQueroPassar);
```

Na sua pagina recebe_variavel.html, uso uma função que lê a url em busca da sua variável na url.

```js
// função pra ler querystring
function queryString(parameter) {  
              var loc = location.search.substring(1, location.search.length);   
              var param_value = false;   
              var params = loc.split("&");   
              for (i=0; i<params.length;i++) {   
                  param_name = params[i].substring(0,params[i].indexOf('='));   
                  if (param_name == parameter) {                                          
                      param_value = params[i].substring(params[i].indexOf('=')+1)   
                  }   
              }   
              if (param_value) {   
                  return param_value;   
              }   
              else {   
                  return undefined;   
              }   
        }

var variavel = queryString("minhaVariavel");
```

Comment: Acredito que retornar undefined seja mais correto do que false quando o parâmetro não for encontrado.

Comment: mermão bixo, muito bom @alex-sander... Inovador!

Answer (score 8):

Utilizando os novos de HTML5, é possível gravar dados (apenas do tipo `string`) no cliente, sem necessidade de utilizar alguma linguagem no servidor (ASP.NET, MVC, PHP, etc.).

HTML5 tem vários modos de Storage (suporte a estes se encontra no [html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage)<sup>em inglês</sup>. Um deles é localStorage, o outro é sessionStorage. Utilize-os assim:

```
<script>
  var dados = JSON.stringify($('input').val());
  sessionStorage.setItem('chave', dados );

  //... depois ...

  var dadosArquivados = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('chave'));
</script>
```