# Passando o valor de um input

Tags: javascript, html

Sou inciante e tho com uma duvida que aparentement simples mas eu não achei uma respota, mto provavel que eu tho deixando uma coisa boba passar, mas eu não estou conseguindo passar um valor de um input do tipo text dentro de um form pra um outro arquivo html, onde esta errado? A variavel que esta em outro arquivo que deveria guardar esse valor não esta recebendo objeto nenhum?

````
    <form action="./teste2.html" method="post">
        <input type="text" id='teste' name='teste'>
        <button type="submit">clique</button>
    </form>

</body> 

------ teste2-----
<script>
```try{
        var b = document.getElementById('teste').value
        window.alert(b)
    }catch(error){
        window.alert(error)
    }

    </script>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como vc está pegando uma variável post em um arquivo .html?

Fiz um código exemplo de como enviar e receber por POST.

index.php

```
<?php
    $teste = $_POST["teste"];

    if (!empty($teste)) {
        echo ("<script>alert('Recebi o valor: $teste')</script>");
    }
?>


<form action="./index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id='teste' name='teste'>
    <button type="submit" onClick={mostraValor()}>clique</button>
</form>

<script>
    function mostraValor() {
        var valor = document.getElementById('teste');
        alert("Valor: "+valor.value+" Enviado!");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Então eu não posso enviar informações pra um arquivo em formato html? Eu sei que eu não posso manipular dados em html mas no body tem o js, essa informação que tento passar não chega até o script? Eu sou inciante realmente. Poderia ficar soh no js e html sem php msm? Vlw pela atenção o//

Comment: Não por Submit/POST, mas voce consegue passar através da URL.
Exemplo:
No Index.html
window.location = "index2.html?variavel=123";

Comment: vlw mano, então post voce usa apenas pra mandar em arquivos que manipulem dados. Encontrei uma serventia pra usar o get então, como eu faço pra pegar esse parâmetro da da url? tipo sla pegar cada valor que foi passado pra url e jogar td em um array

Comment: Tem um amigo aqui do site que ja faz uma pergunta parecida, de uma olhada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75557/passando-valores-js-para-outra-pagina-html

Lembre-se, todos nós fomos iniciantes em algum momento e sempre haverá outros momentos que precisaremos aprender novas tecnologias e nos tonaremos iniciantes novamente. Continue estudando e sucesso!

Answer (score -2):

Boa noite Guito! tudo bem?

Experimente substituir o "submite" por "submit".

```
<button type="submit">clique</button>
```

Comment: Eu tinha visto esse errinho dps de postar e esqueci de editar dsclp, mas o problema ainda persiste