# Executar comandos JavaScript pelo PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Estou com o seguinte problema, não consigo executar comandos JavaScript vindo do PHP.

Pagina **verificar-horario.php**

```
<?php
  echo 'alert("teste")';
?>
```

Pagina **index.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'verificar-horario.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: dados,
    success: function (data) {
       return data;
   }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tem que incluir a função pra funcionar

```
<?php
  include "verificar-horario.php";
?>
```

edit:
espera... lendo melhor eu não entendi qual a sua intenção em criar um `alert` dessa maneira... Se for pra simular um dado que viria do php, não seria mais simples passar diretamente? (ou seja, sem javascript)

Comment: Na verdade eu coloquei um alert como exempo, mas na verdade eu gostaria de chamar outro codigo.

Comment: Entendo, essa resposta aqui é bem completa sobre https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58965/139524

Answer (score 0):

Basta colocar da seguinte forma:

```
<?= ("<script>alert('teste')</script>");?>
```

Abra as tags php, feche e depois coloca o script, esse exemplo não nos traz o escopo da necessidade... não dá pra ajudar muito. Essa pergunta está meio sem sentido...

Mas estará totalmente fora dos padrões recomendados.
Procure separa os arquivos por tipo e inclui-los seguindo as boas práticas de programação.